# How can I sort GeoJson file showing defined tags?

Tags: sorting, dictionary, tags, leaflet, geojson

Good morning to all and thank you for your help.
I'm working in a map page (map.html) create by leaflet library that take data from a external geojson file called water_well.js. This file, previously generated by overpass service is just a list of markers. every Marker have some proprerties. Follow an exemple:

```
    "properties": {  
            "operator:type": "international",            
            "is_in:district": "west_mamprusi",
            "is_in:region": "northern",
            "source:date": "2012-02-11",
            "source:ele": "gps",
            "water_wells:source_type": "borehole"
          },
```

The main page extract those data from the file before with this javascript:

```
var wwMarker = L.geoJson(water_well, {
            pointToLayer : function  (feature, latlng) {
            lat = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
            lng = feature.geometry.coordinates[1];
            //following code that make error
            op_type = feature.properties.operator_type;
            district = feature.properties.is_in:district;
            region = feature.properties.is_in:region;
            source_date = feature.properties.source:date;
            source_ele = feature.properties.source:ele;
            source_type = feature.properties.water_wells:source_type;
            .....
```

I'm sure the problem is my Zero javascript knowledge, but I'm not a programmer and I do this map for my NGO engaged in water wells in Burkina Faso.

The script for extraction of the data don't work in  this point:

```
op_type = feature.properties.operator:type;
```

The problem is ":" because is invalid character.

The second question is that not all markers in the first file called water_well.js have the same "properties" filled ad actually it is possible that someone  have different  group of "properties like those two:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": "node/1606958159",
  "properties": {
    "@id": "node/1606958159",
    "amenity": "drinking_water",
    "man_made": "water_well",
    "name": "puits 4"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -3.6235696,
      12.02171
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": "node/1913126817",
  "properties": {
    "@id": "node/1913126817",
    "ele": "170.8000030517578",
    "grid_proximity": "grid_further_500_m",
    "is_in:district": "builsa",
    "is_in:region": "upper_east",
    "man_made": "water_well",
    "operational_status": "open",
    "operator:type": "individual",
    "pipe_connection": "no",
    "pump": "manual",
    "seasonal": "another_pattern",
    "source": "MVP,Columbia University",
    "source:date": "2012-02-14",
    "source:ele": "gps",
    "water_wells:source_type": "unprotected_well"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -1.2430456,
      10.3233693
    ]
  }
},
```

maybe it is possible to extract all properties of each item independently from which one is present or not..... This can be de better way to solve the problem but I've no idea how to do that.

This is what I do (ckick the water tap to see pop-up): [www.h2openmap.org/map](http://www.h2openmap.org/map)

This is almost what I would like to do (ckick the water tap to see pop-up): [overpass-turbo.eu/s/7Ov](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/7Ov)

Thank you for spending your time reading my question.
Have a nice day everyone, Francesco

Comment: Could you be a little more clear? "the easy way to sort all defined tagx excluding undefined" make no sense at all. Please edit you question and explain, in detail what you want to sort... Only the properties with `:` in them? Sort by what? Propertyname? Properyvalue? By alphabet? Amount? You can sort in dozens of ways. If you want to have a decent answer, you'll need to ask a descent question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you definitively say the truth! My ugly English do not help me at all, anyway I tried to edit the question to make it decent.

Answer (score 0):

You can access those properties using the bracketnotation, instead of using:

```
district = feature.properties.is_in:district;
```

Use bracketnotation:

```
district = feature.properties['is_in:district'];
```

Reference on property-accessors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Now if you want to do something based on if a property exists there is a `hasOwnProperty` method available on objects. Since `feature.properties` is an object you can use that in a condition:

```
if (features.properties.hasOwnProperty('is_in:district')) {
    // Property exists, do stuff
}

// or

if (!features.properties.hasOwnProperty('is_in:district')) {
    // Property does not exist, do stuff
}
```

If you want to do something base on wether multiple properties exist you can use the `&&` (and) operator:

```
if (features.properties.hasOwnProperty('is_in:district') &&
    features.properties.hasOwnProperty('source:data')) {
    // Properties exist, do stuff
}

// Or

if (!features.properties.hasOwnProperty('is_in:district') &&
    !features.properties.hasOwnProperty('source:data')) {
    // Properties do not exist, do stuff
}
```

You could use the `||` (or) operator to see if at least one of the conditions matches:

```
if (features.properties.hasOwnProperty('is_in:district') ||
    features.properties.hasOwnProperty('source:data')) {
    // At least one of the properties exist, do stuff
}

// Or

if (!features.properties.hasOwnProperty('is_in:district') ||
    !features.properties.hasOwnProperty('source:data')) {
    // At least one of the properties does not exist, do stuff
}
```

Reference for this can be found here under "Logical operators": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

You can use something like to build (or don't build) the data object that you need for your popup. Hope that helps.